# How to call API on form submit in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I have a Joomla Project in which there is a ChronoForm5. Now along with Form Submission, I want to call an API of Quickbase.We have the code for both API and Form in Joomla. I just need to Link API method to Form submit button.

Please help me..